# JUnit test needs to invoke GWT's URL.encode() server side

Tags: java, gwt, junit, tdd

I would like to write a JUnit test for one of my GWT classes that calls `com.google.gwt.http.client.URL.encode(String s)` method. This throws me this exception:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.google.gwt.http.client.URL.encodeImpl(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.URL.encodeImpl(Native Method)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.URL.encode(URL.java:155)
    at com.example.foo.QueryBuilder.appendParams(QueryBuilder.java:44)
```

I understand that this `URL.encode` uses deferred binding based on browser implementation to be effective, but I need to write tests for these classes too. Extending `GWTTestCase` is not enough to fix this unfortunately.

How could I make my JUnit test work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use Unitils and create a Mock of `URL`? I know that `URL` is `final` so it can't be subclassed, but I dimly recall that Unitils's mock utility should be able to get around that.

http://www.unitils.org/tutorial-mock.html has details.

Comment: And so everywhere I use URL in my methods, I should call a getURL() that returns a mock URL instance when run from test and the real URL object when run from browser..?

Comment: URL.encode() is not an instance method so calling it on an instance is really ugly.. I wish there were a nicer solution.. :-)

Comment: Can you isolate the URL.encode() call somehow, pull it into another class which can be mocked or injected at test time?